# What's the difference between the Altruist and Investor badges?

Tags: support, badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between the badges “Altruist” and “Investor”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73257/what-is-the-difference-between-the-badges-altruist-and-investor)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I don't get the exact difference between the Altruist and Investor badges. Can anyone help me understand it?

Comment: yes it is, thanks for notifying me. I will delet my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't actually put a bounty on another's question yet but it seems pretty straight forward.

#### Investor:

> First bounty you offered on another person's question

You put a bounty on someone else's question.

#### Altruist:

> First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question

You award the bounty that you put on someone else's question to an answer.  As in you chose an answer to give the bounty to, not letting it expire.